# python user name and password limit verification to x attempts

Tags: python-3.x

```
users = {'adam' : 'Test123', 'alice' : 'Test321'}
status = ""
status = input("If you have an account, type YES, NO to create a new user, QUIT to exit: ")

while status != 'QUIT':

    if status == "YES":
        u_name = input("Please provide your username: ")
        u_pwd = input("Please provide your password: ")

        if users.get(u_name) == u_pwd:
            print("Access granted!")
            break

        else:
            print("User doesn't exist or password error! You have 2 more attempts!")

    elif status == "NO":
        print("\nYou're about to create a new user on my very first app. Thank you!")
        new_u_name = input("Please select a name for your account!")
        new_u_pwd  = input("Please select a password for your account!")
        users[new_u_name] = new_u_pwd
        print("Thank you " + new_u_name + " for taking the risk.")

    elif status == "QUIT":
        print("Smart choice lol. Please come back in few months")
```

What would be the past way to implement the following:
 - if the user selects YES and provides valid username + pwd = access granted exit loop (I have used `break` in this case) 
 - how would I implement a loop so that after the first `else` statement user will be asked again to enter username and pwd but only for another 2 attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can create a counter, something like:

```
users = {'adam' : 'Test123', 'alice' : 'Test321'}
status = ""
status = input("If you have an account, type YES, NO to create a new user, QUIT to exit: ")
max_attempts = 2
while status != 'QUIT':

    if status == "YES":
        u_name = input("Please provide your username: ")
        u_pwd = input("Please provide your password: ")

        if users.get(u_name) == u_pwd:
            print("Access granted!")
            break

        else:
            if max_attempts > 0:
                print("User doesn't exist or password error! You have {} more attempts!".format(max_attempts))
                max_attempts -= 1
            else:
                print("Too many wrong passwords. Bye!")
                break

    elif status == "NO":
        print("\nYou're about to create a new user on my very first app. Thank you!")
        new_u_name = input("Please select a name for your account!")
        new_u_pwd  = input("Please select a password for your account!")
        users[new_u_name] = new_u_pwd
        print("Thank you " + new_u_name + " for taking the risk.")

    elif status == "QUIT":
        print("Smart choice lol. Please come back in few months")
```

---

**Notes**:

You may also want to implement the following features:

1 - Check if the username exits before prompting for password.
2 - Make `YES` and `NO` case InsEnsiTive.

Comment: Thank you Pedro and please apologize for my late response! It works like a charm :) One question though, could you please tell me how did you manage to increment the number of attempts in the printed message ?